# ValueError: max must be larger than min in range parameter

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a numpy array "delta" as below.

```
delta
Out[28]: 
array([2.73324807, 2.70019904, 3.76618225, ...,        nan, 1.93536938,
       4.24551458])
```

I'm trying to plot a histogram for it using the bin and normed parameter as below.

```
plt.hist(delta, bins = 10, normed=True)
```

This gives me the error as :

```
/Users/tcssig/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/histograms.py in _get_outer_edges(a, range)
    302         if first_edge > last_edge:
    303             raise ValueError(
--> 304                 'max must be larger than min in range parameter.')
    305         if not (np.isfinite(first_edge) and np.isfinite(last_edge)):
    306             raise ValueError(

ValueError: max must be larger than min in range parameter.
```

Comment: According the the answer in the question linked above, the reason is due to the nan value(s).

Comment: Nope, it's not due to the `NaN`. I just tested it and it plots perfectly... At least, with Matplotlib 3.0.2

Comment: @Rightleg What can be the error at my end ?

Comment: @Sarang What's your version of Matplotlib? Open an interpreter and run `import matplotlib; matplotlib.__version__`

Comment: My version is 2.0.2

Comment: In order to handle the Nan values, I needed to define the range parameter as below, its working fine.

Comment: plt.hist(delta, bins = 10, normed=True, range=(0,15])

Comment: I'm also having same problem and it is not due to any non-finite value.